# Can we play multiple audio files using dialog fulfillment webhook in google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I want to play around 20 audios with media response, one after another.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587884/is-their-any-way-to-send-multiple-simple-response-in-dialogflow) link says, we can't send multiple simple response in google assistant. What about media response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's true that you can't send multiple simple responses in Google Assistant, you can make it work by sending one single simple response that contains all your audio files.

Something like that:

```
conv.ask(`
  <speak>
    My first sound <audio src="..."></audio>
    <break time="2" />
    My second sound <audio src="..."></audio>
  </speak>
`)
```

You can learn more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml#markupSSML).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used google assistant but to send multiple audio URLs from dialogflow fulfillment webhook in a single response I store the audio URLs in an array and they get played one after another.

In the following code I am pushing the object containing "url","title" and "type" into an array named 'messages'.

**Code**

```
let payload = {
        "web": {    
            "messages": []
        }
    }
    try {
        ayahs.forEach(function (item) {
            payload.web.messages.push({  
                "url": item.audio,
                "title": item.text,
                "type": "audio",
            })
        });

        raw.response.send({

            "fulfillmentText": `Audio is being played`,  
            "payload": payload
        })
        return;
    }
```